# Invoking java web service from .net returns null - different namespace

Tags: java, asp.net, webservice-client

I have a problem when invoking a java web service method that its object returns null but the xml being returned i can see the right data. I realized that the namespace that asp.net generates when creating the web service is not the same as the namespace in the xml being returned. The namespace being returned has a alias and the generated namespace does not have a alias.

Here is the asp.net namespace:

```
**[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://#$%#@$$#$@$.com/RedFlag/Admin/RedFlagAdmin/v1")]**
```

And the namespace from xml being returned:

```
    **<dlwmin:GetEntityHistoryResponse xmlns:dlwmin="http://#$%#@$$#$@$.com/RedFlag/Admin/RedFlagAdmin/v1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">**
```

How would I be able to change the generated namespace in asp.net?

Comment: As long as the namespaces are equal, the namespace prefix (`dlwmin`) is irrelevant. I'd suspect something else is going wrong.

Comment: Can you try using "Add Service Reference" and pointing at the wsdl? (Assuming there is one)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily call java webservice from .net client if u have wsdl(Webservice Definition Language). If so no issue about namespace

1. Step1 : Copy your wsdl for that particular service
2. Step2 : Create .net application
3. Step3 : YourApplication -> ServiceReference -> Add Service Reference
   and paste your wsdl url there and give a reference_name(it is your
   namespace)
4. Step4: finish
5. Step5: create a c# class on that application
6. Step6: Add namespace on that class eg: using yourreference_name;
7. Step7: A client Object is already created there. Using that object you can call your webservice